# How to encode html to save in Mysql Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a spanish script:

**I have this code in html:**

```
<div class="details"><b>Detalle:</b> acompañado o no de una tableta digitalizadora, te permitirá¡ dar rienda suelta a tu imaginación y conseguir verdaderas obras de arte</div>
```

**I need this output:** (to save in Mysql Database)

```
<div class="details"><b>Detalle:</b> acompaÃ±ado o no de una tableta digitalizadora, te permitirÃ¡ dar rienda suelta a tu imaginaciÃ³n y conseguir verdaderas obras de arte</div>
```

any functions to do it ?

Comment: Why don't you store it in utf8? What's that second character set you're using?

Comment: all content in my database is like the html output example explained above :S

Answer (score 1):

Change your mysql database/ table / column encoding to UTF-8 (and also set the collation to a compatible value).

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE mytable 
MODIFY country CHAR(50) 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Also specify the char set at the PHP side when connecting.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_real_escape_string** — `Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement`

But that is **not recommended** and it's **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5.0.

Use this method with [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0...http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @Jack Yes, i do know that. I was in the process of updating my answer. :)

Comment: @SudipPal Yes, pls check updated/edited answer